# How to sync files from google drive to my asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-realtime-api

Guys please suggest how to implement a filexplorer like funcionality into my webapplication  where the files from google drive got synced.I heard dat google drive api can be used ,if so how is it ?

Answer (score 4):

For a complete guide from creation of files to synchronization, you may refer to [Google Drive REST API Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk#top_of_page).

And, this SO post - [Using Google Drive SDK in stand-alone web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194781/using-google-drive-sdk-in-stand-alone-web-application) might just be what you also need.